# Extremely slow GAE java response time

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm hosting a java app app on app engine, or some reason i see that from today the response times are extremely slow - 10kms + !!! the gae status page shows everything is ok, Does anyone have an answer or similar experience ?

Second issue, i see that many request starts only a few seconds after it has been received, there is a delay in executing the request, does anyone know how i can fix it ?

p.s
I changed my instances from f1 to f2 to see if maybe it will help but the result is the same.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[The GAE Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine) is likely still the best place to ask questions like this.

Could it be that you are just seeing an increased number of [warmup](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Warmup_Requests) [requests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances#Loading_Requests)? In this case going from F1 to F2 will not make a huge difference. Depending on your application instance startup can be reduced by changing the instance class. But this change alone will not reduce the time to a more reasonable response time of ~1 second.

> The following best practices allow you to reduce the duration of loading requests:
>
> - Load only the code needed for startup.
> - Access the disk as little as possible.
> - In some cases, loading code from a zip or jar file is faster than loading from many separate files.

You can also try to [add a few resident instances](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings). The GAE scheduler will then put extra traffic on resident instances and launch new dynamic instances in the background. Since residents are started ahead of time this will hide some latency from users.

Comment: Hi Ingo, after some more deeper research i found out that is issue is related to google - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/60Q1aAlAx_I.
Every day around the time they reset the quota some apps experience the same issue. Nothing to do about it, and google doesn't recognize it as a down time even they should do so !!
Hopefully someone at the google gae team will address this issue and give also clarifications to the customers, otherwise that would become a major issue...

Comment: Thanks for the link! If you can proof that it's not an implementation bug on your side you should at least [file an issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3) and let other developers star it.